# Hide users from the three dots into a library folder from specific users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, view

How can I hide the three dots from a library folder, after the name of the file?

I need that just the admin or other specific role can view the users that are show when accessing the three dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to understand why users get three dots option - this is because of item level edit permission is enabled.

We can achieve this in two ways:

**Approach 1:**

Create Two Views:

1. One for normal user
2. Another for admin user

**For normal user view:**

Select and display the "**Title**" column instead of Title (linked to item with edit menu) - and use Name (linked to document) column if you want to open the document on click of name. This way normal user will not get three dots option and this how we can control it.

And for admin users view select and display the columns as usual way.

**Approach 2:**

Using this approach we can control this in a single view by controlling the access.

Create a custom permission level where remove the "**Edit**" permission and assign this custom permission in item level for the normal users, so that normal users will not get edit option or three dots.

Check the below MSDN documents how item level permission works:

[Edit permissions for a list, library, or individual item](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782?ocmsassetID=HA102833689&CorrelationId=44e5c092-e324-4d2b-918d-24408a173cbf&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
[SharePoint 2013: Break Document Library Permissions Inheritance](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18203.sharepoint-2013-break-document-library-permissions-inheritance.aspx)